# How to read TXT file in batches?

Tags: android

Now I am developing a reader. If the txt file is too big, it will spend a long time to read and no response. So I want to set a method like it can read the txt file in bathes.

I write the below code. It can turn the page back. But it can not page up continuous. How should I do?

```
 Vector string; 
 int begin = 0;

 public void readTxtByPage(String fileName) {
        string.clear();
        FileReader fr  = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(filePath + fileName);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            br.skip(begin);
            String content = "";
            char ch;
            int line = 0;
            int w;
            int len;
            int start;
            FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
            fontHeight = (int) Math.ceil(fm.descent - fm.top) + 2;
            pageLineNum = textHeight / fontHeight;
            float[] widths = new float[1];
            while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) {
                len = content.length();
                w = 0;
                start = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    ch = content.charAt(i);
                    paint.getTextWidths(String.valueOf(ch), widths);
                    w += Math.ceil(widths[0]);
                    if (w > textWidth) {
                        string.addElement(content.substring(start, i));
                        begin += (i - start);
                        start = i;
                        w = 0;
                        line++;
                        if (line >= pageLineNum) {
                            System.out.println("begin===>"+begin);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                string.addElement(content.substring(start));
                begin += (len + 2 - start);
                line++;
                if (line >= pageLineNum) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                br.close();
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it would be best if you did this work in a background thread then, you can tell the reader to sleep, and then notify it when you want the thread to start reading again. That way it wont freeze your UI and it can read the bits in batches. Maybe have the thread be notified during an onTouchEvent.